# Get access to variables in f_grad function after optimization with RcppNumerical

Tags: eigen, rcpp, numeric

I use RcppNumerical for optimization and I need some variables declared in `f_grad` function after the optimization is completed.

To explain my question, let's take the standard example in RcppNumerical package. First of all, we need to create a class.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppNumerical)]]

#include <RcppNumerical.h>

using namespace Numer;

// f = 100 * (x2 - x1^2)^2 + (1 - x1)^2
// True minimum: x1 = x2 = 1
class Rosenbrock: public MFuncGrad
{
public:
double f_grad(Constvec& x, Refvec grad)
    {
     double t1 = x[1] - x[0] * x[0];
     double t2 = 1 - x[0];
     grad[0] = -400 * x[0] * t1 - 2 * t2;
     grad[1] = 200 * t1;
     return 100 * t1 * t1 + t2 * t2;
    }
};
```

The following code is then used for optimization.

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List optim_test()
{
    Eigen::VectorXd x(2);
    x[0] = -1.2;
    x[1] = 1;
    double fopt;
    Rosenbrock f;
    int res = optim_lbfgs(f, x, fopt);
    return Rcpp::List::create(
        Rcpp::Named("xopt") = x,
        Rcpp::Named("fopt") = fopt,
        Rcpp::Named("status") = res
    );
}
```

How can I get access to `t1` or `t2` value after the optimization is completed. I want to mean to value of these variables for the optimization solution.

My example may not be very good for what I am looking for because it is easy to calculate `t1` or`t2` outside the optimization of this example. In my case, I need some variables that are computationally cumbersome. So, if they are already calculated during optimization, why not return them (or have access to their values) after optimization without having to calculate them again outside the optimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use member variables for the variables of interest. For simplicity I am using `public` members here:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppEigen)]]
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppNumerical)]]

#include <RcppNumerical.h>

using namespace Numer;

// f = 100 * (x2 - x1^2)^2 + (1 - x1)^2
// True minimum: x1 = x2 = 1
class Rosenbrock: public MFuncGrad
{
public:
  double t1;
  double t2;

  double f_grad(Constvec& x, Refvec grad)
  {
    t1 = x[1] - x[0] * x[0];
    t2 = 1 - x[0];
    grad[0] = -400 * x[0] * t1 - 2 * t2;
    grad[1] = 200 * t1;
    return 100 * t1 * t1 + t2 * t2;
  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::List optim_test()
{
  Eigen::VectorXd x(2);
  x[0] = -1.2;
  x[1] = 1;
  double fopt;
  Rosenbrock f;
  int res = optim_lbfgs(f, x, fopt);
  return Rcpp::List::create(
    Rcpp::Named("xopt") = x,
    Rcpp::Named("fopt") = fopt,
    Rcpp::Named("status") = res,
    Rcpp::Named("t1") = f.t1,
    Rcpp::Named("t2") = f.t2
  );
}

/*** R
optim_test()
*/
```

Result:

```
> optim_test()
$xopt
[1] 1 1

$fopt
[1] 3.12499e-15

$status
[1] 0

$t1
[1] -2.849634e-09

$t2
[1] -4.809313e-08
```